# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in login loop with missing .Xauthority file

Tags: 18.04, xorg, login, lightdm, gdm

My computer running Ubuntu 18.04 is stuck in a login loop. I am using lightdm as my display manager, but trying to switch to gdm3 didn't fix the problem (I was still stuck in a login loop).

I have tried to follow the fixes found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) to fix it, but after running `ls -la` there is no `.Xauthority` file in my home directory. I think this is related to my login loop problem, but I am not sure how to create a new `.Xauthority` file?

Update: I switched to `gdm3` and can now login with Unity for a few seconds. The desktop loads but after a minute I am in a login loop again.

Comment: A new `.Xauthority` file should be created when you successfully start an X-based desktop session. AFAIK not having one initially is not a problem in itself. I suggest you look for an `.xsession-errors` file (e.g. `tail ~/.xsession-errors`) to see if it throws additional light on the real issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but trying to read the error file yields an error because there is no `.xsession-errors` folder in the home folder either. Output from `tail ~/.xsession-errors` is `tail: cannot open '/home/fdrc/.xsession-errors' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: Is your home directory encrypted by any chance?

Comment: No, it isn't...

Comment: its too late but maybe of use to some one else. 
In my 18.04 command `xauth` returns `Using authority file /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`

Answer (score 3):

Method 2 in [this article](https://medium.com/@satyabratbhol/how-to-get-rid-of-login-screen-loop-in-ubuntu-feead4cb2302) worked for me. I am using an old Sony Vaio laptop and think the issue is a graphics problem.

> Reinstalling Ubuntu lightdm.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge lightdm
> sudo apt-get install lightdm
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
> ```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think simply installing `lightdm` (second step) included the reconfigure step.  During the installation, I was asked to select between `gdm` and `lightdm`, which was the same thing that the reconfigure step did (third step).

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your graphics card driver.

First, see what driver you need:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Then download the recommended driver for your graphics card. For example, if the recommend driver was `nvidia-390`:

```
 sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

Comment: #CAUTION# This destroyed my almost-working GUI into a frozen GUI

Comment: The first cmd returns nothing, should I install the driver anyway?

Comment: I also did `apt-get install gdm3` first, this combined with the above advice after worked for me.