# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in login loop with missing .Xauthority file and .ICEauthority

Tags: 18.04, login, xorg

[Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in login loop with missing .Xauthority file](https://askubuntu.com/q/1067219/1038711)
I am having same problem specified in the given link . Can someone please help me

Comment: Please, describe things you have tried and say what went wrong.

Comment: i have tried this https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/1038711 but everytime  i get .Xauthority file missing ...

Comment: also when i tried "sudo apt purge gdm3" then rebooted ...i am able to login but as i again install gdm3 and start it ..again i am stuck in infinite loop

Comment: Try Budgie. It looks nice and seems stable: `sudo apt install budgie-desktop`

Comment: Have you tried `touch ~/.Xauthority`? Owner of file is your user: `9839386 -rw-------   1 spacer spacer   51 Jan 28 18:43  .Xauthority`

Comment: i am able to login now ... after running this command "sudo apt purge gdm3" and then rebooting but  not when i ran command "clear" in terminal ....it showed "The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable"

Comment: What `echo $PATH` shows? You could add it to PATH: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`