# Unable to install recommended nvidia-driver-390 in19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, 19.10, gpu-driver

I'm having problems logging in to 19.10, and following some suggestions (e.g. [ubuntu-18-04-stuck-in-login-loop-with-missing-xauthority-file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067219/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-in-login-loop-with-missing-xauthority-file)), `ubuntu-drivers devices` shows nvidia-driver-390 as recommended driver
[image]

When I `sudo apt install_nvidia-driver-390` it fails
[image]

And trying `sudo apt --fix-broken_install` fails [image]

How can I get this sorted? Thanks.

Comment: Don't post pictures of your screen. [Edit] your question and copy in the commands and output, using proper formatting.

Comment: @OrganicMarble When I boot in recovery mode, I do not know how to copy-n-paste; the video driver is broken, the cursor doesn't work, and the usual copy commands seem absent. Maybe you could suggest how to copy the commands and output, so anyone else in the same predicament (maybe me in a few hours) knows how to comply.

Comment: I missed you were in recovery mode! Understand now. I was finding it hard to read the last screen especially on my tablet last night; looks better on  a  real device. Anyway, check this out: https://askubuntu.com/q/1067183/243321

Comment: @OrganicMarble thanks for that link; yes it looks like the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug with Ubuntu. [package libnvidia-gl-390 (not installed) failed to install/upgrade: new libnvidia-gl-390:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2 (NOT FIXED)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1768050)

The workaround I did was #5, Yuri's improvement of Alexandre's suggestion

> Try
>
> # for FILE in $(dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-340 | awk '{print $3}'); do echo $FILE; done
>
> first and choose the correct number for substring `{print $3}`
>
> For example for Russian locale it will be $2:
>
> # for FILE in $(dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-340 | awk '{print $2}'); do dpkg-divert --remove $FILE; done